# Excel/ How to convert number of date to

Tags: excel, date, date-formatting, date-conversion

How can I convert number of date to number of month or year.
Such as..

```
Number of Date: 40
Number of Month: ?
Number of Year: ?
```

Comment: What is that you exactly need? You have to be more clear in asking question.

Comment: @zzaewon, please elaborate your question, Thanks.

Comment: zzaewon, do you have an Integer number (40) and you want to see which month that number corresponds to? Same for year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Month and Year functions

If this is what you want
[image]

then this is how you do it
[image]